# Activate Windows XP in VMWare?

Tags: windows-xp, vmware

Running Windows XP in VMWare, how should activation be handled?

Last time I did this, I do not remember having to do any activation. Now it is asking me to activate Windows XP.

Am I suppose to buy and use a real WinXP key?

What is this about a "Windows XP Mode" I'm hearing about that you can enable in VMware to activate it?

> The availability of Windows XP Mode is equivalent to a free license to Windows XP operating system.

My host machine runs Win7.

My goal is to get WinXP running in VMWare the simplest way, but this activation is giving me issues (such as that WinXP doesn't seem to be sold anymore). I Googled around and found that VMWare has a `xpmode.enabled = "TRUE"` feature which instantly activates Windows XP (with limits, like only once), but I do not know anything about it or how to use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Licensing issues when using a physical WinXP disk in VMware?](http://superuser.com/questions/50195/licensing-issues-when-using-a-physical-winxp-disk-in-vmware)

Comment: [Windows XP Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-xp-mode) is a Windows 7 feature and is not related to VMware.

Comment: http://www.mydigitallife.info/run-xp-mode-in-vmware-workstation-or-player-with-activation-intact/ mentions VMWare

Comment: You are only licensed to use "XP Mode" if you own certain versions of Windows 7.

Comment: @techie007 I'm running Win7 Pro 64bit

Comment: I should have been more specific,  you are only licensed to use the XP Mode image via Windows 7's in-built Virtual PC.  You [get XP Mode from MS](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx), you can't just use any old XP image just because you own 7. :)

Comment: I'm very confused. VMWare has a `xpmode.enabled = "TRUE"` feature, so what exactly does this do and why am I not allowed/licensed to use it?

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question and explain what you've done to get to the point you're at, and to clarify what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @techie007 Good point, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, yes, you need a valid license and activation for each copy of Windows you intend on using.  Real machine or VM, doesn't matter.

Comment: Is WinXP still sold today?

Comment: Not really, no.  If you call Microsoft they will do everything in their power to help ensure you are 'legit'.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above: Windows XP mode is a feature of Windows 7. It is essential an XP VM, designed to be run by Microsoft Virtual PC.

VMWare enters into the picture with [their support to load this XP VM into VMWare](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2014936) workstation/player, etc. The line `xpmode.enabled = TRUE` is from the `.vmx` configuration file that defines a VMWare VM.

A blog that appears to have pretty good step-by-step instructions for the whole thing is here:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10911/run-xp-mode-on-windows-7-machines-without-hardware-virtualization/